# update panel not working for iframe, why?

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe, updatepanel

### NOTE

- please do provide the solution to the problem. thnku
- must achieve the ajax type functionality for the controls of the page displayed within the iframe, please suggest some cure. any cure.

the contents(button) withing the iframe are causing complete post back

- i have used update panel, script manger, on the main page
- and also on the pae displayed in the iframe

even then post back occurs

### note

i check this using the current time of day in the label.

here are the codes.

### default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  </link>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <table style="width: 100%;" align="center" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFF99" nowrap="nowrap" width="100%" 
                    style="width: 100%;" colspan="2">
                    Logo and pic here 
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap" style="width: 20%;" valign="top" width="20%"  bgcolor="#CC00CC">
                    Side Left

                    <br />
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Menu will come here"></asp:Label>
      <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="small" 
                                onclick="size_iframe_small" />
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="big" onclick="size_iframe_big" />


                            <br />
                            <!--Source HTML codes by Quackit.com 
                            http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/scrolling_images.cfm
                            -->

<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="5" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 2, 0);" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 5, 0);"  >
<div>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="100px" 
                                ImageUrl="~/Images/Water lilies.jpg" Width="100%" ></asp:Image>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="Page0004.aspx" Target="I1" CssClass="hyperlink_marquee" BackColor="#FFFF99">PAGE0004</asp:HyperLink>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</div>

</marquee>


      </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>

                    <div>
                    This DOESNOT have AJAX, 
                    <br />
                    notice the postback
                    <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="POSTBACK" />
                    </div>

                </td>
                <td align="left" bgcolor="#006600" nowrap="nowrap" style="width: 80%;" valign="top" width="80%">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>

                   Content Center <br />
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" >
                    below is a iframe
                    <br />
                    frame border is one to display effect.                    
                    </asp:Panel>
                            <iframe id="I1" runat="server" name="I1" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>


                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="#FF99CC" nowrap="nowrap" style="width: 100%;" 
                     valign="bottom" width="100%" colspan="2">
                   copyright pic
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="Aqua" nowrap="nowrap" style="width: 100%;" 
                    valign="bottom" width="100%" colspan="2">
                   bottom links
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>



    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### page source

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title><link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  </link>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTMxNjQzNjAzOA9kFgICAw9kFgQCAw8PFgIeBFRleHQFEDAwOjA1OjIwLjE0MDYyNTBkZAIJD2QWAmYPZBYCAgMPFgQeBkhlaWdodAUGMTAwMHB4HgVXaWR0aAUFNzAwcHhkZIj8iyoBcGPp9uYNf6JDGALbcNPc" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebSite2/WebResource.axd?d=SaMSNOBLKccV2NOTlN-gpw2&amp;t=634143971188437500" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/WebSite2/ScriptResource.axd?d=wSIzE9Mm7k9OISEyoWDsv3U4aXp9CFd2A4oFHH6FT1g6BCLjteDUaab2pkPnDwBpBV94ozt6kAUQ8M2GCuP8p7K6gO-LkSKrRL_6Fka6BBY1&amp;t=ffffffffc9e9457d" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/WebSite2/ScriptResource.axd?d=wSIzE9Mm7k9OISEyoWDsv3U4aXp9CFd2A4oFHH6FT1g6BCLjteDUaab2pkPnDwBpwApHifEXkw8RNjLgUqr8FJOGxAzU11m_nYTGH6QqtL81&amp;t=ffffffffc9e9457d" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBQLe247BDgKM54rGBgK7q7GGCALs0bLrBgLWlM+bAg8dLO2f49U7Nx0cS1fOwVELnlid" />

</div>
    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ScriptManager1', document.getElementById('form1'));
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._updateControls(['tUpdatePanel1','tUpdatePanel2'], [], [], 90);
//]]>
</script>


        <table style="width: 100%;" align="center" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFF99" nowrap="nowrap" width="100%" 
                    style="width: 100%;" colspan="2">
                    Logo and pic here 
                    <span id="Label1">00:05:20.1406250</span>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap" style="width: 20%;" valign="top" width="20%"  bgcolor="#CC00CC">
                    Side Left

                    <br />
                    <div id="UpdatePanel1">

                        <span>Menu will come here</span>
      <br />

                            <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="small" id="Button1" />
                            <input type="submit" name="Button2" value="big" id="Button2" />




                            <br />
                            <!--Source HTML codes by Quackit.com 
                            http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/scrolling_images.cfm
                            -->

<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="5" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 2, 0);" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 5, 0);"  >
<div>
<img id="Image1" src="Images/Water%20lilies.jpg" style="height:100px;width:100%;border-width:0px;" />
<a id="HyperLink1" class="hyperlink_marquee" href="Page0004.aspx" target="I1" style="background-color:#FFFF99;">PAGE0004</a>
<input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" />

</div>

</marquee>



</div>

                    <div>
                    This DOESNOT have AJAX, 
                    <br />
                    notice the postback
                    <br />
                        <input type="submit" name="Button3" value="POSTBACK" id="Button3" />
                    </div>


                </td>
                <td align="left" bgcolor="#006600" nowrap="nowrap" style="width: 80%;" valign="top" width="80%">
                    <div id="UpdatePanel2">


                   Content Center <br />
                    <div id="Panel1">

                    below is a iframe
                    <br />
                    frame border is one to display effect.                    

    </div>

                            <iframe id="I1" name="I1" scrolling="no" Height="1000px" Width="700px"></iframe>

</div>


                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="#FF99CC" nowrap="nowrap" style="width: 100%;" 
                     valign="bottom" width="100%" colspan="2">
                   copyright pic
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="Aqua" nowrap="nowrap" style="width: 100%;" 
                    valign="bottom" width="100%" colspan="2">
                   bottom links
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>





<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
</script>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

### page0004.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Page0004.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page0004" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Page0004</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel199" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="No Postback" />

        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>



    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need an iframe here. Can't you just dynamically add the contents of what you want in the iframe to the UpdatePanel's Controls collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a little bit not understandable what you want to do, but here is your solution

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="test2.aspx.vb" Inherits="test2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="one" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server">I want to be changed</asp:Label>
            <iframe src="test3.aspx"></iframe>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside of the page "test3.aspx" you insert the followng

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="test2.aspx.vb" Inherits="test2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Im an Iframe
        <asp:Button OnClientClick="parent.Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._doPostBack('one', '')" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you see the function `parent.Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._doPostBack('one', '')`
`parent` is used to get out of iframe, now you are on the main page

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._doPostBack` causes a updatepanel postback, if the first argument is the id of the requested updatepanel...

Answer (score 3):

The update panel needs to have triggers defined, so it knows which events for which controls to capture. Because of this, the controls for which you are capturing events need to be visible to the `UpdatePanel`, and thus cannot be within the `iframe`.

**EDIT:**

Triggers can be defined as follows:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- Your content here -->
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

More about how `UpdatePanel`s work can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx).

However, like I said, `Button1` has to be defined within the scope of the UpdatePanel that has knowledge of it. Therefore, if you want to modify a control on `default.aspx` within the `Button1_Click` event handler, then `Button1` and the control to be modified would have to be visible to each other (and therefore not defined within an iframe). You might be able to do what you want by replacing your iframe with a user control that contains the content of page0004, but you would have be sure that all of the controls between default.aspx and the user control would always be there.

Is there a reason you have page0004 defined separately and are injecting it within an iframe?

Comment: okay but please see the code, the upadte panel is also defined in the actual page which is being displayed in the iframe, so the button click is visible to the updatepanel on that page. also please provide a solution

Comment: Right, but there are actually two `UpdatePanel`s defined (UpdatePanel1 and UpdatePanel199), and neither have any triggers defined for them. Therefore, they will not block the full postback because they do not know what to look for. The reason I did not give an 'answer' is that my point is that you cannot do what you are attempting (and hence, that is my answer).

Comment: i have to provide the ajax type function to the "page controls" of any page(aspx page same website) being displayed in the iframe. please suggest something. this triger thing how can it be defined?